# Could not find OpenSSL when compiling BitchX

Tags: openssl

I am trying to compile https://github.com/BitchX/BitchX on Debian --with-ssl, however, ./configure is not finding the OpenSSL libraries...

```
checking for SSLeay in -lcrypto... no
configure: error: --with-ssl given, but could not find OpenSSL.
```

I found this question posted [configure: error: --with-ssl given, but could not find OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46967821/configure-error-with-ssl-given-but-could-not-find-openssl) however, it is unanswered, and incomplete

I have tried

```
 apt install libssl-dev openssl
```

both of which are installed

```
 libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.1.0f-3+deb9u1).
 openssl is already the newest version (1.1.0f-3+deb9u1).
```

Any ideas on what else I might need to install or why BitchX is not finding the OpenSSL libraries?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that BitchX is looking for an older version OpenSSL...

```
apt install libssl1.0-dev
```

Did the trick...

Comment: Run `apt-get install libssl-dev` after compilation to get the current version back